# Introduction to Euler's Phi Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

This is from the Number Theory Book by Joseph Silverman.

This is the introduction before he goes on to Euler's Phi Function.

---

In the previous chapter we proved Fermat's Little Theorem: If p is a prime and
p doesn't divide a, then $a^{p-l} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. This formula is certainly not true if we replace p by a composite number. For example, $5^5 \equiv 5 \pmod 6$ and $2^8 \equiv 4 \pmod 9$. So we ask whether there is some power, depending on the modulus m, such that $a^{???} \equiv 1 \pmod m$ .
Our first observation is that this is impossible if gcd(a,m) > 1. To see
why, suppose that $a^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod m$. Then $a^{k} = 1 + my$ for some integer y, so gcd(a,m) divides $a^{k} -my = 1$. In other words, if some power of a is congruent to 1 modulo m, then we must have gcd(a,m) = 1.

---

I am unable to understand the last 2 lines here

- Then $a^{k} = 1 + my$ for some integer y, so gcd(a,m) divides $a^{k} - my = 1$.

What does the above line mean? $a^{k} - my = 1$ is an equation. How can gcd(a,m) divide an equation?

Then I don't understand how the next line also comes about

- In other words, if some power of a is congruent to 1 modulo m, then we must have gcd(a,m) = 1.

Can someone please help?

Comment: The author is using shorthand to say "$\gcd(a,m)$ divides $a^k-my$ so, since $a^k-my=1$, we see that $\gcd(a,m)$ divides $1$".  Of course, this then implies that $\gcd(a,m)$ is itself $1$.

Comment: How can $\gcd$ divide $1$? It can! Then it is also $1$.

Comment: @lulu - How does the author get gcd (a,m) divides $a^{k} - my$?

Comment: It's obvious.  That gcd divides $a$ so it divides $a^k$ and it divides $m$ so it divides $my$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c \equiv 1 \pmod{b}$, then what this mean is $c-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{b}$ or $c-1$ is a multiple of $b$.

We have $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, hence $a^k-1$ is a multiple of $m$, hence we can find an integer $y$ such that $a^k-1 = my$.

Rearranging the equation,
$$a^k - my =1$$

For $k \ge 1$, by the definition of common divisor, $\gcd(a, m)$ must divide $a$ and it must also divides $m$, hence it must divide $a^k-my$ which is equal to $1$.

$\gcd(a,m)$ divides $1$. The only positive integer that divides $1$ is $1$.

Hence $\gcd(a,m)$ must be $1$.

Comment: By definition of gcd, gcd (a,m) must divide a & must divide b - I understand this. But why must it divide $a^{k} - my$?

Comment: For convenience, let $d=\gcd(a,m)$, we have $a^k \equiv 0 \pmod{d}$ and $my \equiv 0 \pmod{d}$, hence we have $a^k - my \equiv 0 \pmod{d}$.